# Seaborn ticklabels are being truncated

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn

I'm using the Seaborn heatmap function with customized yticklabels. My labels are quite long, and they are being truncated even when I shrink the fontsize. Is there a way to allow longer visible tick labels?

```
ax = sns.heatmap(
        pcolor_data, 
        xticklabels=day_columns, 
        yticklabels=line_sales_by_day['product_name'][0:n_skus].values, 
        annot=True, 
        cbar=True, 
        annot_kws={'size':10}, 
        fmt='g', 
        cmap=cmap
        )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be really helpful to see you code to help you with this. Can you add it to the question please?

Comment: `ax = sns.heatmap(pcolor_data,
            xticklabels=day_columns,
            yticklabels=line_sales_by_day['product_name'][0:n_skus].values,
            annot=True,
            cbar=True,
            annot_kws={'size':10},
            fmt='g',
            cmap=cmap)`

Answer (score 14):

Have you tried the [`tight_layout`](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html) option from `matplotlib.pyplot`?

```
ax = sns.heatmap(...)

ax.figure.tight_layout()
```

Alternatively, you can control the edges of your subplot area with [`subplots_adjust`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust), a method of the `plt.figure` instance, which you can access with `ax.figure.subplots_adjust()`:

```
ax = sns.heatmap(...)

ax.figure.subplots_adjust(left = 0.3) # change 0.3 to suit your needs.
```

Comment: For me, tight layout doesn't work and subplots adjust crushes the plot.